# Browsing unanswered questions - questions that are resolved

Tags: discussion, questions

So I'm browsing the unanswered questions tab and I'm finding questions that are resolved in the comments. Like this one for example

[How to set environment variables in Python and use them in a C extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866602/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python-and-use-them-in-a-c-extension)

Is there a good way to mark questions resolved so that they won't show up in the unanswered questions tab so actually unanswered questions would show up there instead.

Comment: Well, I don't think that our system can auto checks if a question was solved in comments or not.

Comment: No, but if you find a question as such it's a bit unclear what you should or can do. Or what the best course of action is.